# Rounded UITableViewCell only bottom or top corners but it doesn't work Swift iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rounded-corners

I want to round top and bottom corners of 2 UITableViewCell like this : It's what I get on iOS 11

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psb6Y.png)

But I got this on iOS 10:

[Result rectShape.bounds = self.bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cohdb.png)

With that code :

UITableViewCell of blue view

```
import UIKit

class ProductDescriptionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var ProductDescription: UITextView!
public var container: UIView!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    // Set the width of the cell
   self.bounds = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.y + 16, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.size.width - 16, height: self.bounds.size.height)

    super.layoutSubviews()
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    } else {
        let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
        rectShape.bounds = self.bounds// CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x + 16, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.size.width - 16, height: self.bounds.size.height)
        rectShape.position = self.center
        rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:  rectShape.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath

        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        //Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
        self.layer.mask = rectShape
    }
}
}
```

UITableViewCell of purple view

```
import UIKit

class ProductTitleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var ProductTitle: UILabel!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    // Set the width of the cell
    self.bounds = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.y + 16, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.size.width - 16, height: self.bounds.size.height)

    super.layoutSubviews()
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
    } else {
        let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
         rectShape.bounds = self.bounds//CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x + 16, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.size.width - 16, height: self.bounds.size.height)
         rectShape.position = self.center
         rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:  rectShape.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath

         self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
         //Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
         self.layer.mask = rectShape
    }
}
}
```

if I replace self.bounds by the CGRect in comment I got that :

[With rectShape.bounds = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x + 16, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.size.width - 16, height: self.bounds.size.height)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL0Eu.png)

I try to change the self.bounds at the beginning of init() but it's doesn't work too

And I also try to put the code which change corners in layoutSubviews() but in that case the UITableViewCell disappear

I don't one to use only one UITableViewCell and round his corners I really need to round bottom and top corners on to separate UITableViewCell

If you know how I can fix that I will be very grateful
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Add the following extension:

```
func roundCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

Then call it from  layout subviews like below:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    headerView.roundCorners([UIRectCorner.topLeft, UIRectCorner.topRight], radius: kTableViewCornerRadius)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i am using this very simple extension of UIView to make corners round. In cellForRowAt delegate method, after dequeing the cell, just call

```
cell.makeCornersRound()
```

---

```
extension UIView {

  public func makeCornersRound () {

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    self.clipsToBounds = true

  }

}
```